# sun.misc.Unsafe alternative in Android

Tags: java, android

I know that the `sun.misc.Unsafe` (which from what I've understood can be used to [write directly on memory in java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-write-directly-to-memory/)) is only partially implemented on Android (dammit), but I'm porting [Apache Flink](http://flink.apache.org) on Android and there are bunch of instruction like this:

```
private static sun.misc.Unsafe getUnsafe() {
    try {
        Field unsafeField = sun.misc.Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        return (sun.misc.Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null);
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not access the sun.misc.Unsafe handle, permission denied by security manager.", e);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("The static handle field in sun.misc.Unsafe was not found.");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Bug: Illegal argument reflection access for static field.", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Access to sun.misc.Unsafe is forbidden by the runtime.", e);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Unclassified error while trying to access the sun.misc.Unsafe handle.", t);
    }
}
```

Which generate errors at compile time.

So my question is: there is any alternative for the same purpose on Android?